# Stuck on iterating through php object with arrays

Tags: php

```
$data = new Data();
$data->Date='29-07-1902';
$data->Person='Elton John';
$data->Costs[]=array('Expense','100 EUR');
$data->Costs[]=array('Tax','250 EUR');
```

I want to iterate through this object and display it as a HTML table. The following is my attempt so far.

```
<table border="1" style="width:300px">
    <?php
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    echo "<tr><td> $key </td> <td> $value</td></tr>";
}
echo "\n";
?>
  </table>
```

I want this task done by a function. Also the different costs should appear in a new row, so Expense has its own row, and Tax has its own row.

Answer (score 0):

Your array is actually multimensional so you will need to loop again where your values are array, if I understand you correctly this is what you need

```
<table border="1" style="width:300px">
<?php
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    if(is_array($value))
    {
        echo "<tr><td> $key </td> <td></td></tr>";
        foreach($value as $kk => $val)
        {
            echo "<tr><td> $kk </td> <td> $val</td></tr>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "<tr><td> $key </td> <td> $value</td></tr>";
    }
}
echo "\n";
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Your `foreach` is not closed by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Not probably the best method but try:

```
<table border="1" style="width:300px">
<?php
foreach($data as $key => $value) {

    echo "<tr><td> $key </td> <td> $value</td></tr>";
    if(is_array($value)==true){
        foreach($value as $ind){
            echo "<tr>";
            if(is_array($ind)==true){
                foreach($ind as $i=>$v){
                echo "<td> $v </td>";
                }
            }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
}
echo "\n";
?>
</table>
```

However, this won't work if your `$data->Costs[]` has anymore inner array like `array('Expense',array('100 EUR','50 EUR'));`

Comment: OK that kind of worked. Now the row with column 1 "Costs" has "Array" as 2nd column, I want that to be empty. Also what is the best method, and I am trying to do this with a function, that I could use for any object.

Comment: @Elton Is your array structure that you will pass to function remain the same or can it also have nested arrays within?

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border="1" style="width:300px">
    <?php
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
 if (!is_array($value)) {
  echo "<tr><td> $key </td> <td> $value</td></tr>";
 } else {
  echo "<tr><td colspan='2'>$key</td></tr>";
  foreach ($value as $val) {
   echo "<tr><td> $val[0] </td> <td> $val[1]</td></tr>";
  }
 }
}
?>
 </table>
```

This will work in your particular case (if arrays length will not change)... however, not sure about universal solution, but you could tweak this a little (count array values, format table, etc, etc)... :)